# numpy structured arrays: help understanding output

Tags: python, numpy, recarray

I am trying to learn how to use numpy's structured arrays. Specifically, I was trying to add information to more than one field at a time. I tried:

```
import numpy as np

numrec = np.zeros(8, dtype=[('col0', 'int16'), ('col1', 'int16'),
                            ('col2', 'int16'), ('col3', 'int16')])

numrec[['col1','col2']][0:2] = [(3,5), (1,8)]
print numrec
```

The above does not work. The values are not added to the columns specified. What is surprising is that I **do not get any error** when I run it. Can someone please explain what is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are setting values on a temporary.

```
numrec[["col1", "col2"]]
```

returns a copy of the array.  You can see this by the OWNDATA flag.

```
>>> numrec[["col1", "col2"]].flags["OWNDATA"]
True
```

When you index a numpy array with a list, numpy returns a copy of the data.  It has to be a copy, because, in general, the list may not resolve to a regular, ordered view of the underlying data.  (This holds for any numpy array, not just structured arrays.)

Compare

```
>>> numrec[["col1"]].flags["OWNDATA"]
True
>>> numrec["col1"].flags["OWNDATA"]
False
```

Also, if a numpy array is a view, the base member holds the underlying array.

```
>>> id(numrec["col1"].base) == id(numrec)
True
```

Comment: spot on.  It might also be worth mentioning that this is true for all "fancy indexed" arrays, not just structured arrays.  And I'll put a link to this related recent post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127991/can-i-get-a-view-of-a-numpy-array-at-specified-indexes-a-view-from-fancy-index

Comment: Thanks!! I did not know this. So, if I have two lists `listone` (of length 3) and `listwo` (of length 3) can I update first three elements in `'col1'` and `'col2'` of `numrec` to equal these lists simultaneously. I know I can do `numrec['col1'][0:3] = listone` and `numrec['col2'][0:3] = listtwo`. But can I do it together in one command. Thanks.

Comment: Paul, I may not have emphasized it, but that's what I didn't say "When you index a numpy structured array..."  Anyway, I could have made it clearer.  So I just added a parenthetical to that effect.

Comment: Curious2learn, I don't think there is a way to do what you want in one simple command, though I would appreciate someone proving me wrong.