# Create a permuted shallow copy of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing, numpy-indexing

I am looking to have two different views of the same data with the rows in a different order such that changes done through one view will be reflected in the other. Specifically, the following code

```
# Create original array
A = numpy.array([[0, 1, 2],
                 [3, 4, 5],
                 [6, 7, 8]])
B = A.view()[[0, 2, 1], :] # Permute the rows
print("(before) B =\n", B)

# Change a value in A
A[1, 2] = 143
print("(after) A =\n", A)
print("(after) B =\n", B)
```

has the following output:

```
(before) B =
 [[0 1 2]
  [6 7 8]
  [3 4 5]]
(after) A =
 [[  0   1   2]
  [  3   4 143]
  [  6   7   8]]
(after) B =
 [[0 1 2]
  [6 7 8]
  [3 4 5]]
```

but I would like the last bit of that to be

```
(after) B =
 [[0   1   2]
  [6   7   8]
  [3   4 143]]
```

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127991/can-i-get-a-view-of-a-numpy-array-at-specified-indexes-a-view-from-fancy-inde) state that getting a view at *specific indices* is not possible, though the OP for that question is asking about a subset of the array, whereas I would like a view of the entire array. (It seems that the key difference here is slicing vs. smart indexing)

A [different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181092/numpy-views-vs-copy-by-slicing) asking about slicing by *rows and then columns* vs *columns and then rows* has an accepted answer that states *"All that matters is whether you slice by rows or by columns..."*. So I tried dealing with a flattened view of the array..

```
A = numpy.array([[0, 1, 2],
                 [3, 4, 5],
                 [6, 7, 8]])
B = A.view()
B.shape = (A.size,)

A[1, 2] = 198
print("(After first) A =\n", A)
print("(After first) B =\n", B)

# Identity index map
all_idx = numpy.arange(A.size).reshape(A.shape)

# Swapped and flattened index map
new_row_idx = all_idx[[0, 2, 1]].flatten()

C = B[new_row_idx]

print("(Before second) C =\n", C)

# Manipulate through 'B'
B[7] = 666

print("(After second) B =\n", B)
print("(After second) C =\n", C)
```

which gives the following output:

```
(After first) A =
 [[  0   1   2]
 [  3   4 198]
 [  6   7   8]]
(After first) B =
 [  0   1   2   3   4 198   6   7   8]
(Before second) C =
 [  0   1   2   6   7   8   3   4 198]
(After second) B =
 [  0   1   2   3   4 198   6 666   8]
(After second) C =
 [  0   1   2   6   7   8   3   4 198]
```

As you can see, the 4th entry of `C` is unaltered. The suggested solution to the [first post I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127991/can-i-get-a-view-of-a-numpy-array-at-specified-indexes-a-view-from-fancy-inde) is to create a copy, make changes, and then update the original array. I can write functions to wrap this, but this doesn't eliminate the number of times I will be making copies. All it does is hide it from the user.

What am I missing here? Should I be using the `data` attribute of these arrays? If so, what is a good starting point for understanding how to do this?

Comment: Careful with the  Zwinck answer in the second link.  It narrowly addresses the OP question, and shouldn't be taken as a general explanation.  Read the comments.

Comment: There fundamentally is no way to do this, at least in the narrow way this question is framed. Numpy works on contiguous chunks of memory; there are workarounds, but arbitrary permutations of the data will always break contiguity. It's really that simple...

Comment: However, if your fundamental goal is to write to an array in a permuted way, you can do so pretty easily — much more easily than in the code at the bottom of your question. (That is, unless I have misunderstood your goals.) But that's quite a different question than the one you've asked.

Comment: What kind of operations do you want to do on your permuted array?  Simple one-by-one assignment like this or something more involved?  You could possibly subclass.

Comment: My goal is to support different node ID numbering schemes used by different libraries that support operations on/with finite element meshes. The set of node coordinates does not change, but the global ID assigned to them is different. I would like to do this without copying the mesh data since this can be rather large in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

An array has a `shape`, `strides`, `dtype` and 1d data_buffer.  A `view` will have its own `shape`, `strides`, `dtype`, and pointer to some place in the base's data_buffer.  Indexing with a `slice` can be achieved with just these attributes.

But indexing with a list such as your [0,2,1] cannot be achieved this way.  So `numpy` makes a new array with its own data_buffer, a `copy`.  That [0,2,1] index list/array is not stored with the copy.

```
In [43]: A = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [44]: B = A[[0,2,1],:]
In [45]: A
Out[45]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
In [46]: B
Out[46]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

`ravel` shows the order of elements in the data_base:

```
In [47]: A.ravel()
Out[47]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

The order of elements in `B` is different.

```
In [48]: B.ravel()
Out[48]: array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5])
```

In contrast, consider a row reordering with a slice:

```
In [49]: C = A[::-1,:]
In [50]: C
Out[50]: 
array([[6, 7, 8],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2]])

In [52]: A.strides
Out[52]: (24, 8)
```

This is achieved by simply changing the `strides`:

```
In [53]: C.strides
Out[53]: (-24, 8)
```

Transpose is also a view, with changed strides:

```
In [54]: D = A.T
In [55]: D.strides
Out[55]: (8, 24)
```

I was going to show the `C.ravel()`, but realized that reshape makes a copy (even though `C` is a view).

The fundamental point is that anything that `numpy` describes as `advanced indexing` will make a copy.  Changes to the copy will not appear in the original array.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing